# Expression evaluating to None when substr is not found

Tags: python, string

`str.find()` always returns `-1` if not found.
Can I write an expression instead of `str.find()` and `return None` if not found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I sum up, you want something which:

- **Is an expression**
- Evaluates to `None` when not found
- Evaluates to the index when found
- **Does not use a ternary** (so that Python 2.4 can handle it)

---

The only solution I could come up with which satisfies all requirements is this weird thing:

```
(lambda x: x and x - 1)((str.find(substr) + 1) or None)
```

For example:

```
>>> (lambda x: x and x - 1)(('abcd'.find('b') + 1) or None)
1
>>> (lambda x: x and x - 1)(('abcd'.find('_') + 1) or None)
>>>
```

I don't have a Python 2.4 install to test one, so I can only hope it works.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean something like this?

```
def find2(str, substr):
    result = str.find(substr)
    return result if result != -1 else None
```

In Python 2.4, change the last line to

```
    if result != -1:
        return result 
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: Just a note, probably a bad idea to call a variable `sub` since that exists as a function in a few namespaces.

Comment: Tks but my Python 2.4 could not support that:( Is there any other way?

Comment: @ThunderEX: Edited. Why are you still on Python 2.4?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: but that's not an expression any more:( That's because the whole project is running on Py 2.4 and I'm dealing with it.

Comment: @ThunderEX: `find2("hello", "hell")` is an expression just as `"hello".find("hell")` is. You need Python 2.5+ for ternary expressions or use an `if` statement (wrapped in a function for convenience) if you can't upgrade.

Answer (score 5):

```
None if str.find() < 0  else str.find()
```

and if the code duplication bothers you (and it should):

```
index = str.find()
None if index < 0  else index
```

The ternary condition was [added](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html) in 2.5. So if you have an older version of Python you could do this instead:

```
def my_find(str, sub_str)
    index = str.find(sub_str)
    if index < 0:
        return None
    else:
        return index
```

Comment: Tks.My Python 2.4 could not support that:(